# Access token authorization for multiple devices in django-allauth

Tags: ios, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) and [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) for iOS mobile app back-end. I am new to Django Rest Framework and to mentioned ones in particular. Those are great for access token based authorization. As you know when after successful log in user receives an access token and when logged out the access token is deleted. But, in case of multiple devices I assume that user will be logged out from all devices. Is there a way to create access token for each device and use these access tokens for authorization?

Answer (score 2):

When you are dealing with authentication between your own API, your client, and a third-party API, you never want to expose the token for the third-party application to your clients. I've [covered this in the past on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27051810/359284) for `python-social-auth`, **which I recommend looking at for `django-allauth` as well**.

You have said you are using `django-rest-auth`, which maintains a single token per user that is shared across multiple clients. This is very similar to the `TokenAuthentication` that Django REST Framework provides, and it carries many of the same drawbacks. Because all clients share the same authentication token for a user, all clients will be affected if the token has to be revoked for any reason. Even worse, `django-rest-auth` allows users to explicitly "log out", **which immediately revokes the token for everyone**. This works well if only one or two clients will be using your API, and they can handle tokens mysteriously disappearing, but **it does not work well for anything larger**. It also does not support multiple tokens for users, which is what you are looking for.

I typically recommend for APIs to **use a token-based authentication like OAuth**, and `django-oauth-toolkit` tends to be the recommended one for Django REST Framework. This will allow you to essentially proxy requests between the third party and your client, while keeping tokens for users unique to the client. As the tokens are unique to the client, you will not need to worry about a token being revoked or expiring for one client affecting another client, as the tokens will be independent of each other.

OAuth is used by many of the "big names" out there, like [Stack Exchange](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), [Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2), and [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/). While it does not directly support the concept of "logging out", it is usually recommended that you create your own pages for users of your application to revoke tokens for applications, so they have control over who can and can't access the API on their behalf.

Comment: Hi, Kevin, thanks for answer. But how does this approach help to solve multiple device problem?

Comment: I have studied django-oauth-toolkit, but it's not what I actually need. I am not going to deal with client applications, my back-end is only for native iOS app. I have same issue as described  here 
[TokenAuthentication -- Why can there be only one token per user?](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/601)