# Using django-allauth with django-restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

Is there a way of using django rest framework with  allauth for both normal user registration and social registration

Comment: I found this link in the issues section of allauth, but the solution focuses on social providers rather than simple login. How do you cater for all.  https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/360

Comment: possible duplicate of [oauth2 token authentication using django-oauth-toolkit and python-social-auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051209/oauth2-token-authentication-using-django-oauth-toolkit-and-python-social-auth)

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is interested you could use [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) which works with allauth. But there is an error and [this](http://tech.agilitynerd.com/django-rest-registration-with-django-rest-auth.html) is the work around.