# DRF with python-social-auth, and OAuth token authentication

Tags: django, oauth, django-rest-framework, google-oauth, python-social-auth

I'm relatively new to Django and OAuth, so forgive me if this is a silly question.

I have an app which uses DRF and python-social-auth. Currently users can only authenticated with PSA, with Google OAuth 2.0 as the backend service.

Up until now, I have only had 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication' as the only authentication backend, but now I need to support a very specific use case:

We need to have an automated job (a completely separate app, sitting on another server), that queries my app's REST API every X hours, to get some data from my app. Then this automated job will push the data to other sources (not relevant for this question).

I'm trying to figure out the best way / best practice for how this automated job should authenticate with DRF. The automated job is not really associated with any specific user. I suppose I can create a dummy user for the automated job to use, but that seems hackey. Also, I'm thinking that the automated job should request an Oauth token from DRF and authenticate with that, but I'm not sure if that is the right approach here.

Any input here would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: Where is that server? Do you have any security concerns if you put a secret key on that server for authentication ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [oauth2 token authentication using django-oauth-toolkit and python-social-auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051209/oauth2-token-authentication-using-django-oauth-toolkit-and-python-social-auth)