# How exactly work a social login with django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I need to create a webservices to login users. This webservices will be called from Android or iOS app. How exactly does works? I have no idea how does works? Which part make the call to login, the app or webservices? I need to use Python-Social-Auth? or the native app make the login proccess and the webservices save the access token? Someone please guide me with the login process?

Comment: Hi! Have a look at django-allauth (and rest-auth in case you build RESTful API), and how OAuth2 protocol works. In brief, your app should obtain an access token for your app from the social login provider (e.g., Facebook), then submit this token to you web service, and the web service will use this token to check your identity and retrieve as much information about you as you allowed it to do.

Comment: python-social-auth documents that here [signup-by-oauth-access-token](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token).

Comment: possible duplicate of [oauth2 token authentication using django-oauth-toolkit and python-social-auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051209/oauth2-token-authentication-using-django-oauth-toolkit-and-python-social-auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as the other commenters have said theres plenty of other auths you can use, other then python-social-auth. Just with a simple search i was able to find a yeti blog about using python-social-auth with an ios app, they seem to like it enough. They are using Tasty Pie in conjunction and give a few code examples.

https://yeti.co/blog/integrating-django-tastypie-python-social-auth/

I would suggest googling/researching different auth systems and how they might work with android and ios, there seems to be plenty of google groups and blogs about it. If you want your search to return the best results try -

{Insert auth here} with (ios or android) or {insert auth here} auth code for (ios or android)

Also if I may suggest that if your going to use outside third part auth, like twitter/google/facebook try looking into django social auth.
https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth

Here is another blog that digs deep into how to set up auth for ios using a django backend, the guy is using allauth, and his app allows users to go through a login or a third party login(facebook) check it out. http://httplambda.com/a-rest-api-with-django-and-oauthw-authentication/

Hope this helps a little!